# Selenium test, parse Json string from variable

Tags: json, selenium

I am using selenium Selenese to do some functional tests. 
I need to parse the Json content of the body. 
Here is the json:

```
    {"access_token":"ab89978b-   
     74a1-41a6-81e7-7b520ea9d29f","token_type":"bearer","refresh_token":"38a3a34b-09c9-452e-
     b05b-6903770a877f","expires_in":1799,"scope":"read"}
```

I am using the following Selenese command:

```
<tr>
<td>store</td>
<td>
    javascript{
        var jsonstr = '${body}'
        var obj=JSON.parse(jsonstr); 
        var token=obj.access_token;
    }
</td>
<td>token</td>
</tr>
```

But I am getting the following error:

> Command execution failure. Please search the user group at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/selenium-users for error details from the log window.  The error message is: missing ; before statement

Does anyone know how to parse the content of a variable in selenium that contain Json string?

Comment: If the JSON is exactly has you posted it, then it is not valid. The line break after `"ab89978b-` is invalid. See http://jsonlint.com/. Though the error indicates that you are missing a `;` somewhere. Maybe after `'${body}'`?

Comment: no the json is valid, just copy and pasting it while dealing with the indent to post code is why i put it this way

Comment: the error is misleading, something else is wrong, am approaching this the right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use storeEval instead of store

```
<tr>
    <td>store</td>
    <td>{&quot;access_token&quot;: &quot;ab89978b-74a1-41a6-81e7-7b520ea9d29f&quot;, &quot;token_type&quot;: &quot;bearer&quot;, &quot;refresh_token&quot;: &quot;38a3a34b-09c9-452e-b05b-6903770a877f&quot;, &quot;expires_in&quot;: 1799, &quot;scope&quot;: &quot;read&quot;}</td>
    <td>json</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${json}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>var x = '${json}'; var obj=JSON.parse(x); obj.access_token;</td>
    <td>bam</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${bam}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've struggled a bit with this issue So I figured I'd add my own solution, which builds on the solution provided here and might help those trying to get the JSON object itself out:

```
<tr>
    <td>open</td>
    <td>/YOURURL/</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeText</td>
    <td>css=pre:contains("ELEMENTATTRIBUTEYOUWANTTOGRAB")</td>
    <td>json</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${json}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>var x = '${json}'; var obj=JSON.parse(x); obj.ELEMENTATTRIBUTEYOUWANTTOGRAB;</td>
    <td>AC</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${AC}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Selenium IDE & the browsers do not show the html wrapping that actually exist: it makes it hard to grasp at the code.... even though a right click will show the source as a JSON object `{ABCD...}` the actual source has the object prewrapped in a `<pre> </pre>` element. Here, we use that info to select the element, load it in a JSON object, and extract the desired attribute from it.